Use Chrome Angular Dev Tools to target an Ifame Angular App
I have an Angular Application that I am developing, but the app only works when rendered in the iframe of another Angular website that I do not own. Since that top level site is in production mode the Dev Tools do not work and instead give the standard error message: "We detected an application built with production configuration. Angular DevTools only supports development build."
Is there a way to get the Angular Dev tools to target my angular app which is in the iframe at a different origin and is in dev mode. In this case, my app is simply at https://localhost:4200.
I've tried looking for answers else where but haven't seen anyone with a solution.
